# Does Mail.app support Exchange "categories" on emails?

Tags: mail.app, exchange

I've got a team who are all running Outlook on Windows to log into a shared inbox and use "Categories" to delegate incoming work.

A new team member wants to use her Mac, running Mail.app.  I had no problem getting the account set up, but the Category markings are not visible anywhere in Mail.app.  (Flags are, read/unread are, folder structure is, just not Categories.)

Is there a visibility setting somewhere that I'm missing?  Or will I need to get Office Business for Mac so she can do this work in Outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail.app has no categories, but the Outlook 2011 on Mac has.

Also making Mail communicate with Exchange server is tricky, however Outlook 2011 will do that.

So she can still use her mac with Outlook for work, and mail for all other emails.

Comment: In addition to not being able to see the exchange categories, it appears that **messages with a category set are not even synced** to Mail.app!

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if [MailTags3](http://www.indev.ca/MailTags.html) supports categories synchronisation. I haven't tried it personally though.

Comment: Interesting, it looks like you can use MailTags "keywords" and have that shared across an Exchange server and show up in Windows Outlook as a "category": http://support.indev.ca/discussions/mailtags-3-preview-1/5598-windows-compatibility.  (Also haven't tried it, but looks promising!)